# How to collapse a logical vector with AND or OR?

Tags: r, logical-operators

How can I apply the AND `&` or OR`|` operators to a logical vector in R?

For example:

```
a <- c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
```

Is there a simple way to

- Are all elements `TRUE`? Like putting an `&` between each element:

  - when applied to the above vector it would return: `FALSE`
- Are any elements `TRUE`? Like putting a `|` between each element

  - when applied to the above vector it would return: `TRUE`

Comment: `?any`; `?all` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
allTrue <- all(a)
anyTrue <- any(a)
```

The documentation for these functions is linked from `help("&")` or `help("|")`.

Answer (score 1):

`all` and `any` are exactly what you are after, alternatively:

```
sum(a)==length(a) # Are all elements TRUE?

sum(a)>0 # Are any elements TRUE?
```